# How to get list of latest branches that auto exit (no need to press q)?

Tags: git

I here are the commands that I want to achieve in combined.

- `git -P branch` = show the list of branches and **auto-exit**
- `git branch --sort=-committerdate` = show the list of branches in descending order (from latest to oldest)

My question is how to show the list of branches from latest to order that auto-exit according to terminal height (without pressing q)?

> note: I don't want to show the entire list of branches, I just want to show according to terminal height.

Comment: Use a pager that shows the first N lines and then quits, perhaps. If we assume the output from `git branch` fits on one line per branch name, run it through `head -n <num>` where `<num>` is the number of lines in the window, as obtained via terminfo or stty settings or whatever the local equivalent may be.

Comment: By "auto exit", do you mean that you want to output one full screen of text and then drop back to the command prompt, even if there are more lines to display? Sort of like displaying it with a pager that automatically hits Q for you at the stop for the first page?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen when we run `git branch` it shows the list of branches, either you press *q* to to exit and press *enter* key to proceed showing the list. I don't want to proceed show the rest of the list, I just want to exit it but without pressing q.

Comment: Then phd's answer below is exactly what you need, the one with `$LINES`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen can we also do this in commit e.g. `git log --oneline | HEAD $LINES`. tried it but it does not worked?

Comment: ahh nevermind. this one works `git log --oneline -10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the option [`-P`/`--no-pager`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--P) so you can use it here:

```
git -P branch --sort=-committerdate
```

But that could produce long listing. If you want exactly one screen-high output you have to clip it. For example using [`head`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/head)

```
git branch --sort=-committerdate | head -$LINES
```

Bash stores the current terminal height in environment variable `$LINES`; if you don't use Bash you have to get the terminal height yourself. There is no need  to use `-P` as Git doesn't use pager when the output is not a terminal (it's a pipe in the command above).

Comment: hello. thanks for the answer. Can I ask where `$LINES` is being declared, are you talking about `.bashrc` file?

Comment: Bash creates a lot of environment variables automatically. See the section "**Shell Variables**" at [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). Check with `set | less` (press "q" to exit, you know).

Comment: ahh sorry. what I mean, where can we change the value of `$LINES`?

Comment: `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS` are variables maintained by the bash shell to denote the current size of the terminal - https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/environment-variables/ - You can change it with `LINES = 25`, but it will be changed again if you resize the terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

in addition of **@phd** answer..

you can also add your own custom variable inside `~/.bashrc` file. append the variable.

```
export CUSTOMLINE=24
```

and follow the same command given by **@phd**

```
git branch --sort=-committerdate | head -$CUSTOMLINE
```